# contenteditable div como input text

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, input

Tengo un contenteditable div que luce así

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este campo es generado de la siguiente manera

```
<div class="entradaTexto" name="entradaTexto" ng-model="entradaTexto" contenteditable="true" 
style="
   height: 60px; 
   padding: 20px 20px 20px 20px; 
   background-color: #f7f8f8; 
   overflow-x: hidden; 
   overflow-y: hidden;" 
>{{entradaTexto}} </div>
```

La clase "entradaTexto" luce así

```
[contenteditable="true"].entradaTexto {
  white-space: nowrap;
  width:200px;
  overflow: hidden;
} 
[contenteditable="true"].entradaTexto br {
  display:none;

}
[contenteditable="true"].entradaTexto * {
  display:inline;
  white-space:nowrap;
}
```

El problema surge cuando se introduce un texto demasiado largo que abarca más del tamaño del campo, en ese caso, no se puede deslizar el contenido horizontalmente para la edición de este como en los input text

PD: soy consciente de que aplico una clase y un estilo a la vez

Comment: ¿Alguna razón para no usar un textarea?

Comment: Quiero que el campo sea de una sola línea y que con un validador (que ya está hecho) se muestre con un <b> la parte del texto que está mal, por eso no me sirve el típico input, desconozco si con el textarea se pudiese hacer

Comment: ¿Y si ajustas el tamaño de la fuente en relación al largo del texto?

Comment: Es un poco cutre y aun así, el texto a introducir es tan largo que la mayoría de las veces se acabaría con un tamaño de letra ilegible

Comment: Pues insertar un <br> en relación al largo del texto podría ser otra forma, pero al final dependerá de lo que necesites visualmente.

Comment: He conseguido hacer que se desplace horizontalmente cambiando `overflow-x: hidden;` a `overflow-x: scroll;` pero claro, se muestra la barra del slider horizontal, veré si hay alguna manera de ocultarla

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/139163/discussion-between-jaime2m1-and-mauricio-contreras).

Answer (score 0):

Al final he conseguido el resultado que esperaba

Sobre todo con mi navegador hacia falta la siguiente línea
`-webkit-scrollbar-width: none !important;`

Mi código HTML luce así

```
<div class="entradaTexto" name="entradaTexto" ng-model="entradaTexto" contenteditable="true" 
style="
   height: 60px; padding: 
   20px 20px 20px 10px; 
   background-color: #f7f8f8;
">{{entradaTexto}}</div>
```

Con un css

```
.entradaTexto {
  overflow-x: auto !important;
  overflow-y: hidden !important;
  -webkit-scrollbar-width: none !important;
  -ms-overflow-style: none !important;
  /* for Internet Explorer, Edge */
  scrollbar-width: none !important;
  /* for Firefox */
}

.entradaTexto::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none !important;
} 

[contenteditable="true"].entradaTexto {
  white-space: nowrap !important;
  width:200px !important;
} 
[contenteditable="true"].entradaTexto br {
  display:none !important;

}
[contenteditable="true"].entradaTexto * {
  display:inline !important;
  white-space:nowrap !important;
}
```